# Aviation SE has no on-topic page: is it time to come up with guidelines?

Tags: discussion

I was reading [this question about Airline law](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12335/what-loopholes-are-there-in-the-montreal-convention) and my gut instinct was it isn't on-topic here, even though it is related to the air line industry. The first comment posted as of that time seemed to back me up:

@SentryRaven posted:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this rather belongs to legal site, it has nothing to do with aviation in what is defined in the scope of topics.

But then, when one goes to the help site for [on-topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), one sees that there ARE no on-topic guidelines. Perhaps just as bad, the [off-topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) is also empty of aviation specifics.

In the beginning, I am sure (whether a conscious decision or not) it was decided that in order to 'bring in' questions, we didn't want to limit discussions. However, isn't it time to think about what kinds of questions we want, and conversely, don't want, asked?

Comment: Thanks, good meta-question.

Comment: Here's a good place to start; on-topic: Everything to do with aviation including legal regulations, off-topic: Other legal questions.

Comment: We have a few questions here on meta discussing [military](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7/are-combat-flight-and-military-aircraft-on-scope), [RC planes](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8/are-remote-controlled-aircraft-on-topic), "drones" and [aerodynamics](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/431/should-we-answer-non-aviation-aerodynamics-questions). Those would make good reference as well.

Comment: While a duplicate, I agree that we need to actually revise the on and off topic pages.  Perhaps someone can clean up the other page to make it consistent with the other help pages and we can post it!

Comment: trouble is that everything is an awfully broad word. [This question about aviation software](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/structural-design-software-for-airplanes) and [this one about aviation-related movies](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/what-aviation-related-movies-are-there) are potentially related enough to be considered in 'everything'....

Comment: I feel that in general "matters related to the flying community or a reasonable pilot would find interesting" is on topic. Pilots don't care about how software is produced or how many movies are out there.

Comment: @kevin I know a lot of pilots that care about how software is produced, myself included. :) This is SE, after all. Having said that, yes, I agree that it's off-topic here. Also, that question wasn't about how software is produced, but, rather, what software packages are commonly used by aircraft manufacturers (e.g. AutoCAD, Solid Works, Pro Engineer, CFD software, etc.)

Comment: We now have an ["On-Topic"](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/282/what-topics-can-i-ask-about-here) page :-)